# How to open new pages/ from websites from qr scanner in flutter?

Tags: flutter

**The following are the codes I used to open qr scanner(I am using a package called "**barcode_scan**") which works pretty fine but I want to open new pages or open webs after scanning automatically and if I press cancle button I want it to navigate to previous page but my code just prints the result in texts, how do I navigate to pages after I scan, I know I have to use 'url_launcher' but how?**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_barcode_scanner/flutter_barcode_scanner.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';


class MyCustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyCustomWidget> createState() => _MyCustomWidgetState();
}

class _MyCustomWidgetState extends State<MyCustomWidget> {
  String _scanBarcode = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startBarcodeScanStream();
  }

  Future<void> startBarcodeScanStream() async {
    FlutterBarcodeScanner.getBarcodeStreamReceiver(
        '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE)!
        .listen((barcode) => print(barcode));
  }

  Future<void> scanQR() async {
    String barcodeScanRes;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.QR);
      print(barcodeScanRes);
    } on PlatformException {
      barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
    });
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> scanBarcodeNormal() async {
    String barcodeScanRes;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE);
      print(barcodeScanRes);
    } on PlatformException {
      barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Barcode scan')),
            body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Flex(
                      direction: Axis.vertical,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Scan result : $_scanBarcode\n',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
                      ]));
            })));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch result uri string in browser like this. Using:

https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

```
Future<void> launch(String url) async {
  if (!await launchUrlString(url)) {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

```
try {
      barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode('#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.QR);
      print(barcodeScanRes);
      
      await launch(barcodeScanRes);

    } on PlatformException {
      barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }
```

If you want to navigate previous page

```
try {
      barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode('#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.QR);
      print(barcodeScanRes);
      
      Navigator.pop(context, barcodeScanRes);

    } on PlatformException {
      barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }
```

Receive returned value from barcode screen and set it to result variable

```
final result = await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const BarcodeScreen()),
  );
```